# Increment a constant foward iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I've a function taking a constant iterator in parameter and I would like to make a recursive call on the function, but incrementing my iterator by one (without modifying the iterator itself).

The only solution I found was to create a copy of the iterator, and pre-increment this copy to finally pass it as parameter of my function call.

```
func(const FowardIterator & i, const container & c) {
  // lot of very smart code

  FowardIterator next = i;

  ++next;
  func(next, c);
}
```

Is there any simpler way to do this, one which does not involve creating a temporary iterator ?

Comment: You should pass iterators by value anyway.

Comment: Does the forward iterator have operator ++ ( int ) ? If it does then how about func( i + 1, c ) ?

Comment: STL Foward iterator does not support i + n, only Random access iterator do.

Comment: @Seath Carnegie: `i + 1` needs a `RandomAccessIterator`.

Comment: So say `std::next(i)` instead (requires C++11).

Comment: And if you don't have C++11, `std::next` is implementable in about three lines of C++03 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iterator should be extremely fast to copy, so there's really no reason to accept one by `const&`; pass-by-value should be fine, and would allow you to avoid copying the iterator explicitly in the body of the function.

That said, you can also use `std::next` to copy an iterator and advance it all in one step:

```
func(std::next(i), c);
```